# Sort a Pandas DataFrame using both Date and Time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I'm Trying to sort my dataframe using "sort_value" Im not getting the desired output

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('raw data/120_FT DDMG.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('raw data/120_FT MG.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('raw data/120_FT DD.csv')

dconcat = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

dconcat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dconcat['ActivityDates(Individual)']+' '+dconcat['ScheduledStartTime'])
dconcat.sort_values(by='date')
dconcat = dconcat.set_index('date')
print(dconcat)
```

[image: Date column]

Comment: `dconcat=dconcat.sort_values(by='date')`.

Comment: I tried that too. It Didn't work

Comment: Try this - `dconcat.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

`sort_values` returns a data frame which is sorted if `inplace=False`.
so `dconcat=dconcat.sort_values(by='date')`

or you can do `dconcat.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)`

you can try this;

```
dconcat = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])

dconcat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dconcat['ActivityDates(Individual)']+' '+dconcat['ScheduledStartTime'])
dconcat.set_index('date', inplace=True)
dconcat.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(dconcat)
```